# TypeError when using reticulate package to call a function from Python peakutils package

Tags: python, r, reticulate, peakutils

I want to use the Python package `peakutils` from within R. To do this, I use the `reticulate` package. Here's an example of what I'd like to do.

```
# Load packages
library(data.table)
library(reticulate)

# Set RNG
set.seed(-1)

# Synthetic data function
foo <- function(x) sin(x) * sqrt(x) + rnorm(length(x), 0, 0.1)

# Create data
dt <- data.table(x = seq(0, 10, by = 0.1))
dt$y <- foo(dt$x)

# Import Python library
pu <- import("peakutils")

# Indices pf peaks
ind <- pu$indexes(dt$y, thres = 0.7)

# Have a look at data
plot(dt)
points(dt[ind], col = "red", pch = 19)
```

[image]

That's great and works as expected. Now, say I want to change the `min_dist` parameter, which according to the [documentation](https://peakutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html) is an integer. I pass `min_dist = 3L`, like so:

```
# Indices pf peaks now with a larger minimum distance
ind <- pu$indexes(dt$y, thres = 0.7, min_dist = 3L)
```

and receive the following error:

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
>   TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an
>   index

It is expecting an array with a single element that is an integer, but – as far as I can see – this is *exactly* what I'm passing so why am I receiving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the `y` argument rather than the `min_dist` argument. The solution below was originally posted on the `reticulate` GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/606).

```r
# Load packages
library(data.table)
library(reticulate)

# Set RNG
set.seed(-1)

# Synthetic data function
foo <- function(x) sin(x) * sqrt(x) + rnorm(length(x), 0, 0.1)

# Create data
dt <- data.table(x = seq(0, 10, by = 0.1))
dt$y <- foo(dt$x)

# Import Python library
pu <- import("peakutils")

# Indices pf peaks
ind <- pu$indexes(as.array(dt$y), thres = 0.7, min_dist = 3L)

# Have a look at data
plot(dt)
points(dt[ind], col = "red", pch = 19)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>